# $.ajax not defined - JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a problem with using ajax.

I have this JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateDepartment()
{
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "getSubSubjectsList",
         data:{
            subjectName: "",
          },
          headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json'
             },
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1",



          success: function (response) {


           var subSubjectsList =  $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
           window.alert(JSON.stringify(response));
           var select = document.getElementById("sub_subjects_select");
                 for (var i = 0; i < subSubjectsList.length; i++) {
                     var option = document.createElement("option");
                     option.text =subSubjectsList[i].description;
                     option.value = subSubjectsList[i].subjectObj.view;
                    //window.alert(subSubject.description +"  "+subSubject.id+"  "+subSubject.subjectObj.id+"  "+subSubject.subjectObj.view+"  "+ subSubject.departmentObj );


                      select.add(option);
                    }
                 openDialog('changeDepartment');
                 },
           //$("#subSubjectDiv").html( response ); call to another page .jsp

        error: function(xhr,textStatus,err) { window.alert(JSON.stringify(xhr) + " ... "+textStatus+" ... "+err);}
     });





}


</script>
```

When I run it I got this error:

```
editContact?contacting_id=8:392 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined updateDepartment @ editContact?contacting_id=8:392onchange @ editContact?contacting_id=8:251
```

I have function named "getSubSubjectsList" in my controller.

This is my controller function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSubSubjectsList", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody  List<sub_subject> getSubSubjectsList(@RequestParam("subjectName") String subjectName) {


    subSubjectsList= Sub_SubjectDAO.getSubSubjectsList(language);
    return subSubjectsList;
}
```

What I need to do for this issue?

Comment: did you load jquery before running your script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer.. I forgot to add this script in my Html code:

`<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

Load the jquery is important!